# How do I correctly build a graph with depth of n from my sql data

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have following data

```
| From | To |
+------+----+
|    1 |  2 |
|    2 |  3 |
|    2 |  4 |
|    5 |  1 |
|    6 |  5 |
|    5 |  7 |
+------+----+
```

Now I would like to query my data with CTE enhanced select, like

```
DECLARE @start INT;
SET @start = 1;
DECLARE @depth INT;
SET @depth = 1;

WITH
[Recursive] AS
(
    SELECT
        1 as [level],
        *
    FROM    [dbo].[myTable]
    WHERE   @start IN ([From], [To])
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        t1.[level] + 1,
        t2.*
    FROM    [Recursive] t1
    JOIN    [dbo].[myTable] t2
        ON    t1.[level] < @depth
        AND
        (
            t1.[From] IN (t2.[From], t2.[To])
            OR t1.[To] IN (t2.[From], t2.[To])
        )
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    [From],
    [To]
FROM    [Recursive]
```

With this small test-data the performance is quite ok - but when increasing the data and depth the execution gets really bad (caused by multiple-column join).

What is the correct statement for such a task?

Comment: What is your expected output? Your query only returns (1, 2) and (5, 1), I don't see the rationale behind that.

Comment: @Lieven i'm not building up a real tree, rather a graph: each relation has a `From` and a `To`. a graph shows incoming and outgoing relations. that's why, if we use depth of 3, all supported records should be selected

Comment: Are cycles allowed? Your data looks unidirectional but it seems you wish to search bidirectional. Is that assumption correct?

Comment: @Lieven cycles are allowed. yes, i would like to search it bidirectional, as i have to build up eg outgoing relations if i have an incoming one (and the depth is sufficient) and add other outgoing relations to this id (which is then an incoming)...

Comment: I have been playing around with some ideas, mainly by adding all rows from your input table switched around to prevent the OR clause. It worked but it wasn't faster or more readable than your original solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I use C# on my *client*-side, I ended up pulling all the data to the client and to the graph-calculation-stuff in C#. It's way more performant and as memory-footprint is not the problem, I am happy with that :)